# how to insert "1" to each element in array? (python)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

For example if i have:

```
array1 = [[-1, -1],
[-1, 1],
[1, -1],
[1, 1]]
```

How can i use np.insert to insert a column of [1, 1, 1, 1] so that output becomes:

```
array1 = [[1, -1, -1],
[1, -1, 1],
[1, 1, -1],
[1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all the inserted values are the same, you can pass a single integer as the value:

```py
array2 = np.insert(array1, 
                   obj=0,
                   values=1, 
                   axis=1)
```

**Follow-up question:**

> If I want the values added to be random numbers between -0.1 and 0.1, what should I write instead of the 1 in values?

`np.insert()` converts the inserted values to the type of the original array, so first make sure that the original array has type `float`, e.g.

```py
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([[-1, -1],
                   [-1, 1],
                   [1, -1],
                   [1, 1]], dtype='float')

# create four random numbers between -0.1 and 0.1
random_array = 0.2 * np.random.rand(4) - 0.1

array2 = np.insert(array1, 
                   obj=0,
                   values=random_array, 
                   axis=1)
```

Comment: hey just one question, if i want the values added to be random numbers between -0.1 and 0.1, what should i write instead of the 1 in values?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
np.insert(array1, 0, [1, 1, 1, 1], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> numpy.insert(arr, obj, values, axis=None)

The `obj` is the index 0. You only want to insert the `value` `1` along the axis `1`. The following should work:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = [[-1, -1],
[-1, 1],
[1, -1],
[1, 1]]

np.insert(array1, obj=0, values=1, axis=1)
```

Result

```
array([[ 1, -1, -1],
       [ 1, -1,  1],
       [ 1,  1, -1],
       [ 1,  1,  1]])
```